# Interop.Outlook - get all emails(Items) within a subfolder

Tags: c#, outlook, office-interop

I'm trying to get the body(or any other attribute) of an email which is inside a specific folder in outlook.

I'm using the `interop.outlook` assembly. 
I have done the following so far. But when trying to call an item in `myInbox`, there are no attributes at all.

```
Application myApp = new ApplicationClass();
        NameSpace mapiNameSpace = myApp.GetNamespace("MAPI");
        MAPIFolder myInbox = mapiNameSpace.GetDefaultFolder(OlDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox).Folders["QC"];
```

The following brings no expected attributes

```
 myInbox.Items[1].
```

In addition, the next step is to click a link inside the body of the email. just want to know if it's even possible.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how I'm doing;

```
Outlook.Application myApp = new Outlook.Application();
Outlook.NameSpace mapiNameSpace = myApp.GetNamespace("MAPI");
Outlook.MAPIFolder myInbox = mapiNameSpace.GetDefaultFolder(Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox).Folders["QC"];
```

This should bring all mails in Inbox. Then call;

```
Outlook.MailItem mailItem = myInbox.Items[1];
```

This `mailItem` contains all the attributes you need.

Explanation: The `mailFolder.Items[1]` is an `Outlook.Items` object which has no attributes you require. You need to cast it to an `Outlook.MailItem` object to achieve this.

Comment: Any suggestions for how to "click" a link inside an email?

Comment: If you got the `mailItem.HTMLBody` property to a string then look for a pattern of the link like `<a href="http://www.example.com">XYZ</a>` and extract the link and execute it.