# Get all Outlook emails (including ones on server)

Tags: vb.net, powershell, outlook, interop

Edit3: I think I'm going to include Microsoft Graph API as well. Using the interop is acceptable as long as enough data is cached. Otherwise, I'll use the online method.

Edit2: I'd even be fine with changing Outlook's offline settings, but prefer to not have to do this for all folders.

Edit: [Programmatically accessing archived mails in an Exchange folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39595941/programmatically-accessing-archived-mails-in-an-exchange-folder)

The third suggestion listed seems to be what I'm looking for. It's possible I've opened an instance in cached mode. I'm not sure yet how to do that through the interop.

This post helped me out: [Interop.Outlook - get all emails(Items) within a subfolder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35620003/interop-outlook-get-all-emailsitems-within-a-subfolder)

My issue is that it only retrieves some of the messages. I believe it has to do with how many messages Outlook has synced. If I browse the folder in Outlook, the bottom of the list says "Click here to view more on Microsoft Exchange". When clicked, naturally, it shows the rest of the messages.

Is this possible through the interop?

```
Add-Type -LiteralPath "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Visual Studio Tools for Office\PIA\Office15\Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.dll"
$oApp = [Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.ApplicationClass]::new()
$oNamespace = $oApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
$TargetFolder = $oNamespace.GetDefaultFolder([Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlDefaultFolders]::olFolderInbox)
$MailItemsWithAttachments = $TargetFolder.Items | Where-Object {$null -ne $_.Attachments} | Select-Object Subject, Attachments
```

The last line is where I assume needs adjusting. Feel free to provide an example in VB/C#, I'm familiar with both.

Comment: I do not recognize this as vb.net.

Comment: Personally I used a different Interop DLL to try and figure this out and I removed the where-object on the last line and modified select-object to `*` just to test this out to try and help. It retrieved 1500 mail objects for me. Perhaps its just your DLL? I used one located here, `"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\ADDINS\Microsoft Power Query for Excel Integrated\bin\Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.dll"` -if using a different dll worked for you let me know so I can post as an answer.

Comment: @shadoe2020 Nope, none of those adjustments helped. It might have to do with how much you sync in Outlook. Does your Outlook show "Click here to view more" before exceeding 1500 items?

Comment: @Mary It's not VB.NET, but that's my primary language. However, I ended up writing it in PowerShell, due to my requirement's simplicity. It should be reasonably easy to read, and you can provide VB/C# examples (as I doubt there will be a PowerShell example of this).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is happening is it's pulling only what is cached for you, you will not be able to pull any more unless you set the cache period to "All" or disable the caching. You can disable by going to account settings, click "change" and then uncheck use cached exchange mode.

Comment: Yes, something I'd prefer not to have to do. If I could set "download from all time" to just one subfolder, that'd be fine. Otherwise, maybe I should attempt this via Exchange Online API.

Comment: I think you're totally on the right track with that. Good luck!