# Outlook restrict method not finding some items in Inbox and/or sent box

Tags: vba, outlook

Hi i have a script that loop through an excel sheet to check if i received a response for emails i have sent. the script was working fine for the last couple of months but now it doesn't find (random?) certain items in my inbox (outlook)
i have built a DASL filter based on 3 criteria found in each emails.
I am not sure if this is an issue with referencing my Outlook folders. when counting items in my Inbox restricted by the filter, items.count returns 0 which is incorrect.
i know my DASL filter is not the best but i struggle a bit with string concatenation. i am sharing a screenshot of an email i can successfully find.The criterias used to find that email are highlighted in red.

[screenshot of test email](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JcG6A.png)

Sub Search_InboxAndHighlight()

```
Dim myOlApp As New Outlook.Application
Dim objNamespace As Outlook.Namespace
'Dim objFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
Dim objFolder As Outlook.Folder
Dim filteredItems As Outlook.Items
Dim Sup_ENg_Number As Range
Dim OGDD_Programs As Range
Dim strFilter As String
Dim compName As String
Dim supNumber As String
Dim Program_type as String

'set a reference to cells we are going to loop through
Set OGDD_Programs = ActiveSheet.Range("A2", "A" & Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)


Set objNamespace = myOlApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set objFolder = objNamespace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
Set fol = objNamespace.Folders("myEmailaddress").Folders("Sent Items")


"loop through cells on activesheet

For Each Sup_ENg_Number In OGDD_Programs

  supNumber = "'" & Sup_ENg_Number.Value & "'"
   compName = Sup_ENg_Number.Offset(, 1).Value
   compName = "'" & compName & "'"
  Program_type = "'" & Sup_ENg_Number..Offset(, 3)Value & "'"

   ' filter to search sup_eng_number  and company name in body of the eemail
     strFilter = "@SQL=""urn:schemas:httpmail:textdescription"" ci_phrasematch " & supNumber
     strFilter = strFilter & " AND "
     strFilter = strFilter & """urn:schemas:httpmail:textdescription"" ci_phrasematch " & compName
     strFilter = strFilter & " AND "
     strFilter = strFilter & """urn:schemas:httpmail:textdescription"" ci_phrasematch " & Program_type
  
   'restrict items to lookup to be only of the filter "strFilter"
    Set filteredItems = objFolder.Items.Restrict(strFilter)
    Set SentFilteredItems = fol.Items.Restrict(strFilter)

    If filteredItems.Count = 0 AND SentFilteredItems.Count = 0 then

      Sup_ENg_Number.Interior.Color = vbRed
   end if
Next Sup_ENg_Number 

 MsgBox "Completed!"

'If the subject isn't found:
If Not Found Then
    'NoResults.Show
Else
   'Debug.Print "Found " & filteredItems.Count & " items."

End If
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
'myOlApp.Quit
Set myOlApp = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Post an image of an email that is supposed to be a match with your DASL filters. ``Program_type`` is not defiined.

Comment: i manually rewrote the code above and yes i defined Program_type in real code, unfortunately i cannot show a screenshot because it contains sensitive information ..i played around yesterday and remove the Program_Type criteria, the filteredItems.Count returns something but i need to use all 3 criterias to find the correct email

Comment: Create a dummy mail just for testing and post an image of it. I tried to create the DASL filters to match yours, using ``View->View Settings->Filter->Advanced->Field->Frequently-used-fields->Message``, but I did not get the same filters! How did you create them?

Comment: i created them as shown in my script, i will try to create a dummy email

Comment: I cannot apply this advice on my machine, but you may have better luck.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/59546486/1571407

Comment: See [Access outlook emails online](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70647363/access-outlook-emails-online)

Answer (score 0):

If you have more than one inbox, the default inbox may no longer be what it was.

Instead of

```
Set objFolder = objNamespace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
```

be consistent

```
Set objFolder = objNamespace.Folders("myEmailaddress").Folders("Inbox")
```

Comment: Hi , I tried the above too without success,, my issue is only happening with 7 emails out of hundreds .. and it is also returning an incorrect count on my Sent items box

Comment: If Sent Items folder results are also impacted you could edit the question to remove "Inbox versus Sent Items". Consider simplifying the question by removing Excel and hardcoding the data into the sample code and as well adding a sample email text without sensitive information.

Comment: i sent myself a test email, no issue, i have emails that i was able to find yesterday but today my script can't find them.

Comment: i sent myself a test email, no issue, i have emails that i was able to find yesterday but today my script can't find them. i don't believe the script would find some emails and 2 days after that it won't find them anymore. i am showing a screenshot of my test email , no problem finding it with my script

Comment: Edit the question to add the most up to date information. Indicate the results are inconsistent. Include the test email there. Provide enough detail for potential responders to prove/disprove a problem in the code.

Answer (score 0):

I rewrote the code to remove Excel.

This <s>apparently good</s> code follows the example in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/outlook/pia/how-to-search-for-a-phrase-in-the-body-of-items-in-a-folder.

<s>It finds older mail but does not find a new test email with "Test" in the body.</s>
Forgot I was testing both default and secondary mailboxes. Code works.

```vb
Option Explicit ' Consider this mandatory
' Tools | Options | Editor tab
' Require Variable Declaration
' If desperate declare as Variant

Sub Search_Inbox()

    ' Code for Outlook not Excel
        
    Dim objFolder As folder
    Dim fol As folder
    
    Dim filteredItems As Items
    Dim SentFilteredItems As Items
    
    Dim strFilter As String
    Dim supNumber As String
    
    Dim i As Long
    
    'Default Inbox
    'Set objFolder = Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
    'Set fol = Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderSentMail)

    'Any inbox
    Set objFolder = Session.folders("myEmailaddress").folders("Inbox")
    'Set fol = Session.folders("myEmailaddress").folders("Sent")
    Set fol = Session.folders("myEmailaddress").folders("Sent Items")

    'https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/outlook/pia/how-to-search-for-a-phrase-in-the-body-of-items-in-a-folder
    If (Session.DefaultStore.IsInstantSearchEnabled) Then
    
        ' compare this sample filter to your filter for supNumber
        strFilter = "@SQL=" & Chr(34) _
          & "urn:schemas:httpmail:textdescription" & Chr(34) _
          & " ci_phrasematch 'office'"
        Debug.Print strFilter
        
        supNumber = "Test"
        'Debug.Print supNumber
        supNumber = "'" & supNumber & "'"
        'Debug.Print supNumber
        
        ' filter to search for supNumber
        strFilter = "@SQL=""urn:schemas:httpmail:textdescription"" ci_phrasematch " & supNumber
        Debug.Print strFilter
        
        'restrict items
        Set filteredItems = objFolder.Items.Restrict(strFilter)
        Debug.Print "Found " & filteredItems.Count & " inbox items."
        
        Set SentFilteredItems = fol.Items.Restrict(strFilter)
        Debug.Print "Found " & SentFilteredItems.Count & " sent items."
        
        If filteredItems.Count = 0 And SentFilteredItems.Count = 0 Then
            Debug.Print "No items found."
        Else
            For i = 1 To filteredItems.Count
                Debug.Print filteredItems(i).subject
                Debug.Print filteredItems(i).ReceivedTime
                Debug.Print filteredItems(i).body
            Next
            
            For i = 1 To SentFilteredItems.Count
                Debug.Print SentFilteredItems(i).subject
                Debug.Print SentFilteredItems(i).ReceivedTime
                Debug.Print SentFilteredItems(i).body
            Next
            
        End If
        
        MsgBox "Completed!"
        
    Else
    
        MsgBox "Experiment with like. May be buggy as well."
        
    End If

End Sub
```

You state in a comment "i have emails that i was able to find yesterday but today my script can't find them."

If there is no explanation about the unreliability you see, you could experiment with like rather than ci_phrasematch. You might consider using `.Find`.

Comment: thanks i am going to try your code, also i just noticed something, my code is setting a reference to my offline Inbox which contain very few emails compare to the server stored Inbox :  2800 items versus 48K items