# Access outlook emails online

Tags: vba, search, outlook

I would like to make VBA script that can search and list hit-emails-information. I am on halfway and found my script only search in local replicated data instead of online original data. Therefore search results obviously limited to recent correspondences. I would highly appreciate advice from someone who can help on solving it to search online data thoroughly.

My script is like below.

```
    Set objOutlook = Outlook.Application 
    Set objOutlookAcct = objOutlook.Session.Accounts(TargetAccount)
    Set objOutlookStore = objOutlookAcct.DeliveryStore
    Set MyInbox = objOutlookStore.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
    Set MyItems = MyInbox.Items
```

And MyItems is the subject population of search which only includes replicated local data.

Comment: Hello Dmitry and Eugene. Thank you for your valuable advice. I am considering utilizing "Redemption" to refer to online data. It is now clear to me that Microsoft model does not simply cover the way to access online data. To sync full e-mail is simple but the setting can not be changed in company IT policy.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing you can do in Outlook Object Model to counter this - you can either change the sync options to "All Items" instead of a time range or you would have to switch to Extended MAPI (C++ or Delphi only) or [Redemption](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/) (any language including VBA - I am its author) to open the folder in the online mode before you search (but then it will be slower of course):

```
MAPI_NO_CACHE = &H0200
MAPI_BEST_ACCESS = &H0010
set OomFolder = Application.ActiveExplorer.CurrentFolder
set Session = CreateObject("Redemption.RDOSession")
Session.MAPIOBJECT = Application.Session.MAPIOBJECT
set RdoFolder = Session.GetFolderFromID(MyInbox.EntryID, , MAPI_NO_CACHE Or MAPI_BEST_ACCESS)
MsgBox "Number of items in the online folder: " & RdoFolder.Items.Count
```

Answer (score 0):

The Outlook object model doesn't provide anything for searching items online (on the server). Instead, you can sync the local data in Outlook with the server and then search for the updated/received data. The [SyncObject](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.syncobject) class   which represents a Send\Receive group for a user. The [SyncObject.Start](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.syncobject.start) method begins synchronizing a user's folders using the specified Send\Receive group. For example:

```
Public Sub Sync() 
 Dim nsp As Outlook.NameSpace 
 Dim sycs As Outlook.SyncObjects 
 Dim syc As Outlook.SyncObject 
 Dim i As Integer 
 Dim strPrompt As Integer 
 Set nsp = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI") 
 Set sycs = nsp.SyncObjects 
 For i = 1 To sycs.Count 
Set syc = sycs.Item(i) 
strPrompt = MsgBox( _ 
 "Do you wish to synchronize " & syc.Name &"?", vbYesNo) 
If strPrompt = vbYes Then 
 syc.Start 
End If 
 Next 
End Sub
```

The [SyncObject.SyncEnd](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.syncobject.syncend) event is fired immediately after Microsoft Outlook finishes synchronizing a user's folders using the specified Send/Receive group.

```
Dim WithEvents mySync As Outlook.SyncObject 
 
Sub Initialize_handler() 
 Set mySync = Application.Session.SyncObjects.Item(1) 
 mySync.Start 
End Sub 
 
Private Sub mySync_SyncEnd() 
 MsgBox "Synchronization is complete." 
End Sub
```

Also you may consider using a low-level API on which Outlook is based on - Extended MAPI or any third-party wrappers around that API such as Redemption. It simplifies your life much when dealing with Extended MAPI. In that case you can point out which data access you want to get (see Dmitry's reply to you).